# How to add a child layout to parent layout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to group two widgets in a `QGridLayout` so I can move them both at the same time as one widget in the parent Layout, I've red that the `addLayout` can the the work however I couldn't find a class with that name but instead I find `addChildLayout` and `addChildWidget` but I don't know how to make them work!

Here's the code I test on:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5.2

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.QtCore import*
import sys

class ClassName(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        parent_layout = QGridLayout()

        self.text1 = QLineEdit()
        self.text2 = QLineEdit()
        # I want to make Button1, text3 and progress widgets in one line
        # I want Button1, text3 in a child_layout
        Button1 = QPushButton("Button1")
        self.text3 = QLineEdit()
        self.progress = QProgressBar()


        self.text1.setPlaceholderText("text 1")
        self.text1.setFixedWidth(524)

        self.text2.setPlaceholderText("text 2")
        self.text2.setFixedWidth(85)

        self.progress.setValue(0)
        self.progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

        Button1.setFixedWidth(125)

        self.text3.setReadOnly(True)
        self.text3.setPlaceholderText("text 3")

        parent_layout.addWidget(self.text1, 0, 0)
        parent_layout.addWidget(self.text2, 0, 1)
        parent_layout.addWidget(self.progress, 1, 1)
        parent_layout.addWidget(Button1, 1, 0)
        parent_layout.addWidget(self.text3, 2, 0)

        self.setLayout(parent_layout)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = ClassName()
dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Result:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is set the columnspan argument when you call `addWidget()`. For example from your image, it looks like text1 should span two columns of your grid. If you take a look at the [qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qgridlayout.html), you'll see that addWidget is overloaded and can accept the arguments rowSpan and columnSpan. Using that information, you should be able to populate your window like this.

```
parent_layout.addWidget(self.text1, 0, 0, 1, 2)
parent_layout.addWidget(self.text2, 0, 1)
parent_layout.addWidget(Button1, 1, 0)
parent_layout.addWidget(self.text3, 1, 1)
parent_layout.addWidget(self.progress, 1, 2)
```

Let me know if that works out.